# how to make php login with android

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication

The most confusing question today for all beginners is that how can we make login to user using my sql and php because we find many commands being deprecated. Can somebody explain best way to make a login either be its basicnamevaluepair or httppost or what ever. It will help everybody. 
But i tried but didnot work like this

```
    <?php
require "myfile.php";

$username=$_POST['username'];
$userpass=$_POST['password'];
echo 'username is '.$username;
echo 'password is '.$userpass;
$mysql_qry="Select * from employeedata where username like '$username' and password like '$userpass'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{echo 'Login Success';
}
else{
echo 'Not success!';
}
?>
```

Here is myfile.php

```
<?php
$db_name="employee";
$mysql_username="root";
$mysql_password="";
$server_name="localhost";
$conn=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);
if($conn)
{
    echo 'Success!';
}
else{
    echo 'Not success!';
}
?>
```

For android i used

```
 URL url = new URL(myurl);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream o = connection.getOutputStream();
        InputStream i = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(o, "UTF-8"));
       Log.v("adsluser",email);
        String postData = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(postData);
//        writer.flush();
       // writer.close();
       // o.close();
        backresult = "";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i, "iso-8859-1"));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            backresult += line;

        }


        return backresult;


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error i got here is that data didnot get posted in that page. If i set default value and try it is success. Also it is success from browser too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error I find here is that you are reading InputStream after opening OutputStream but before posting your data.
Post your data and then only read InputStream because input stream is only expected received after you post data.
Try this

```
URL url = new URL(myurl);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream o = connection.getOutputStream();


        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(o, "UTF-8"));
       Log.v("adsluser",email);
        String postData = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(postData);
   writer.flush();
        writer.close();
       o.close();
        backresult = "";
 InputStream i = connection.getInputStream();        

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i, "iso-8859-1"));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            backresult += line;

        }


        return backresult;


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: mannnn best answer. I wasted 2 weeks just placing that line their and searching for mistake. Your answer worth a million dollers.

Answer (score 0):

if the goal is simply to do a login, I would suggest leave all of this and go use firebase. Here is the link:
[Link to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)

It is an amazing tool complete with a database, auth, and much more. I think it is the easiest way to get up and running.

Comment: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/  refer this link